# What is the official definition of number literals in XPath 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

I am trying to figure out the official definition of what kind of numbers are allowed in XPath 1.0 syntax.

Through trial and error, I believe I have it pinned down as:

```
^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$
```

In other words:

- Optional `-`
- Leading `+` is not allowed
- No exponent
- Redundant zeros before or after the decimal point can be omitted

And this seems to be true for both number literals and for using `number()` with a string value, except that `number()` allows leading and trailing whitespace.

With the exception of the second bullet, this appears to be the same as [xsd:decimal](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal), but I can't find any mention of it in the section on [Numbers](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#numbers) or any mention of any XSD type that it would correspond to.

Is this in fact defined anywhere? If so, where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

80% of the way through typing this question I found my answer, so I figured I should follow through and post it here in case anyone else is ever looking for this obscure bit of trivia.

The production for [Number](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-Number)s is defined in the [Lexical Structure](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#exprlex) section:

> [30]    Number    ::=    Digits ('.' Digits?)? | '.' Digits 
>   [31]    Digits    ::=    [0-9]+

The leading minus sign is handled in the [UnaryExpr](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-UnaryExpr) production:

> [27]    UnaryExpr    ::=    UnionExpr | '-' UnaryExpr

And the set of values accepted by `number()` is defined in the definition of that function:

> a string that consists of optional whitespace followed by an optional minus sign followed by a Number followed by whitespace is converted to the IEEE 754 number that is nearest [(according to the IEEE 754 round-to-nearest rule) to the mathematical value represented by the string; any other string is converted to NaN

Here "Number" refers to lexical production [30] above.

Comment: The 'Lexical Structure' section is the first place I would have looked.